# Generate HTML page from Swagger documentation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, swagger, swashbuckle

I have simple ASP.Net WebApi that use Swagger, added it using Swashbuckle. I need to show Swagger documentation as a HTML page from my ASP.Net app.

I don't know where to start, any suggestion or link would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you activate Swagger you can see the docu online at

https://yourpath/swagger/index.html (or something like that).

Comment: I know that, I need to generate HTML page that holds my API from asp.net app

Comment: You can generate a documentation file (set it in the project properties for each build) and use the content, to show it on a page.

Comment: Thanks, any link how to do that?

Comment: Just go this way:
Right Klick your Project -> Properties -> Build -> Set XML Documentation File